# NUnit 3.0.1 for C#: how to run a few test from the same class in parallel way

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nunit-3.0

Im using VS2012 + Resharper. I created NUnit test projest (NUnit 3.0.1) and added Parallelizable attribute for all test classes. It works in parallel way but only when started for all classes. When it's started for one class, it runs test one-by-one. Im staring tests from Visual Studio's Resharper window.

**How to run a few tests from one class in parallel way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of NUnit 3.0 (including 3.0.1) individual tests are not yet parallelizable. The lowest level of parallelization is currently between TestFixtures.

If you are using `Parallelizable.Children` - this currently has the same functionality as `Parallelizable.Fixtures`. Allowing individual tests to be run in parallel is planned for future releases, at which point `Parallelizable.Children` will be the attribute you want, I believe.

This is documented [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute).

Comment: Thanks, I thought so:). Do you know how to define child tests?

Comment: I believe in this context, child tests refers to any tests inside a TestFixture/Suite. i.e. if you have the `Parallelizable` attribute on a class, all tests inside that class will be the 'child tests'.

Comment: So I created test class ( test fixure) with parameter ` [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]` but all tests are run one-by-one

Comment: Yes - see the first sentence of my answer. =) Individual tests within a test fixture are not parallelizable in NUnit 3.0.1. This will be implemented in later versions of NUnit. If you use `ParallelScope.Children`, it will currently function the same as `ParallelScope.Fixtures` and once when the NUnit team implement the feature, the tests will run in parallel.